# how to make NSScollview scroll properly (Swift)

Tags: macos, swift

It seems like I'm having problems with methods of NSScrollview class, I want to fill a scroll view to be filled with NSBox's once I click on a button.

```
@IBAction func filler(sender: AnyObject)
{
    for (var k = 0; k  <= 20; k++)
    {
        var box: NSBox = NSBox()

        var pos = NSRect(x:10, y:170-(70+5)*k, width:488, height:70)
        box.frame = pos

        scroller.documentView = box
     }
}
```

once I click the button, just the last box appears on a position that's not exactly the one I specify...

If I alternatively use th method `.contentView.addSubview(box)` it shows all the boxes but the scroll does not scroll properly, when I scroll, I can see some of the boxes that are at the bottom but as soon as I release the scrolling, the boxes come to the previous position.

```
@IBAction func filler(sender: AnyObject)
{
    for (var k = 0; k  <= 20; k++)
    {
        var box: NSBox = NSBox()

        var pos = NSRect(x:10, y:170-(70+5)*k, width:488, height:70)
        box.frame = pos

        scroller.contentView.addSubview(box)
     }
}
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the boxes as subViews to separate view, set its size correctly and set that view as the documentView of the scroll view.

BTW, are you sure that `170-(70+5)*k` is correct for the y position?